# Ordered pairs and set -builder as function class

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to read "Set Theory" by Thomas Jech and i'm confused by statement in page 14 (1.14) 
It states:

> The separation Axioms follow from the Replacement Schema.
>   **(1)** Given $\varphi$, let $F = \{(x,x):\varphi(x)\}$.
>   **(2)** Then $\{x\in X:\varphi(x)\}=F(X)$, for every $X$.

What I don't understand is how **(2)**  follows form **(1)**, specifically:
if we have set $S = \{e_1, e_2, e_3 \dots \}$ and if all elements are not set themselves then
form **(1)** and $F\cap S= F(S)$ assuming all elements of $S$ satisfy $\varphi$ we get $\{\{\{e_1\}\},\{\{e_2\}\},\{\{e_3\}\} \dots\}$, set of singleton sets. This is from definition of ordered pair and singleton set:
$(a,b) = \{\{a\},\{a,b\}\}$ then
$(a,a) = \{\{a\},\{a,a\}\} = \{\{a\},\{a\}\} = \{\{a\}\}$
but from **(2)** we clearly get set of original elements, or set $S$.
What do i miss here?

**Edit1:**
Is nontation $F= \{(x,y):\varphi(x,y,p)\}$ shorthand or convention for something? And if it is for what exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's some confusion over the notation "$F(X)$": by definition, $F(X)=\{y: \exists x\in X((x, y)\in F)\}$. It should then be clear that $F(X)=\{x: \varphi(x)\}$: we have $$x\in F(X)\iff \exists y\in X((x, y)\in F)\iff \exists y\in X(y=x\wedge \varphi(x))\iff x\in X\wedge \varphi(x).$$

Comment: In other words, $F$ is the restriction of the identity to the class $\{\,x:\phi(x)\,\}$.

Comment: @Noah thank you for quick answer. You are correct there was confusion over notation of "F(X)"